# How do I make CompareValidator skip validation on empty target control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes and two comparevalidators. I want to ensure that one is lower than the other. Both text boxes also have to have required validation.

The code for one of the textboxs and its validator is

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRiesgo_Total_Des" MaxLength="18" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="compareRiesgoDesdeHasta" ControlToValidate="txtRiesgo_Total_Des"
                        Font-Size="XX-Small" Type="Double" ControlToCompare="txtRiesgo_Total_Has" ErrorMessage="Desde < Hasta<br>"
                        Operator="LessThan" Display="Static">
                    </asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: I don't know whether the CompareValidator can handle this scenario out of the box. Have you considered using a CustomValidator control, instead?

Comment: I did, but couldn't make it work, and it seems there may be a way to handle this in CompareValidator.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a CustomValidator is the best approach because it would also be a good idea to check that the text is a int and not a string.

In your aspx:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCompareInt" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Must be lower"
ControlToValidate="txtRiesgo_Total_Des"
OnServerValidate="Riesgo_Total_Des_Validate" 
Display="Dynamic" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRiesgo_Total_Des" MaxLength="18" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRiesgo_Total_Has" MaxLength="18"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" Text="submit"/>
```

In your code behind:

```
protected void Riesgo_Total_Des_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    int lowerNum;
    int higherNum;
    bool lower = int.TryParse(txtRiesgo_Total_Des.Text, out lowerNum);
    bool higher = int.TryParse(txtRiesgo_Total_Has.Text, out higherNum);
    if (lower && higher)
    {
     if (lowerNum >= higherNum)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using!